# Explaining an SML function and its type

Tags: function, types, sml

So I have this function:

`fn (f,g,x) => g(f(x));`

The type of this function is:

`('a -> 'b) * ('b -> 'c) * 'a -> 'c`

Does the function mean that f represents 'a, g represents 'b, and x represents 'c? Also in that case, how does `('a -> 'b)` come about? because does that not mean f -> g?

Apologies if this is an obscure and poorly written question.

Could someone explain to me how the type of that function is calculated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a diagram that might help:

```
   ('a -> b') * ('b -> 'c) * 'a  ->   'c
    ^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^     ^     ^^^^^^^
fn (   f      ,     g      ,  x) => g(f(x));
```

For any types you want `'a`, `'b`, and `'c`,

- `f` takes an `'a` and returns a `'b`
- `g` takes a `'b` and returns a `'c`
- `x` is an `'a`.

And the `'c` at the end says that, given those things, our function returns a `'c`.

So how do you get a `'c`?  Well, since `x` is an `'a`, you can use `f` to get a `'b`:

```
x : 'a
f(x) : 'b
```

now we have a `'b`, and if you give `g` a `'b` it will give you back a `'c`:

```
g(f(x)) : 'c
```

and that's how we arrived at the body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The type of a function that maps `(x1, x2, x3)` to `e` is `τ₁ * τ₂ * τ₃ -> τ'` where `τ₁` is the type of `x1`, `τ₂` is the type of `x2`, `τ₃` is the type of `x3` and `τ'` is the type of `e`. That's the definition of a product type: it's the type of a tuple of elements of these types.

Here `f` has a type of the form `'a -> 'b`, `g` has a type of the form `'b -> 'c` and `x` has a type of the form `'a`. It's apparent that `f` and `g` have function types since they're applied to an argument. Furthermore, since `f` is applied to `x`, the argument type of `f` is the same type as the type of `x`: both are `'a`. Likewise, the return type of `f` and the argument type of `g` are the same type (`'b`) since `g` is applied to the value returned by `f`.

I don't know what you mean by “represents”. `'c` stands for the type of `x` (which is alos the type of the argument of `g`). (This can be any type: the function is polymorphic.) `'b` stands for the type of the argument of `g` (which is also the type of the return value of `f`). `'a` stands for the type of the argument of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers already sufficiently explain how to derive the type for this function, I will just add that if the `x` argument were instead curried and the composition of `f` and `g` flipped, the function would be equivalent to the composition operator that is already built into Standard ML:

- `fn (f, g) => (fn x => f (g x))` is equivalent to
- `fn (f, g) => (fn x => (f o g) x))` is equivalent to
- `fn (f, g) => f o g` is equivalent to
- `fn (f, g) => (op o) (f, g)` is equivalent to
- `op o`.